# how can I improve speed of rendering pins on google map for angular?

Tags: angular, performance, google-maps, rendering, google-maps-markers

I'm using Google Maps for Angular (https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/google-maps-as-an-angular-component) and it works fine except when there's a large number of markers. Then the rendering of the markers slows down significantly. I'm wondering if there's a way to improve the rendering speed.

59 markers renders instantly:

[image]

35,000 markers can take up to an hour:

[image]

Here is my template:

```
<div class="map-container">
    <google-map
      #map
      height="100%"
      width="100%"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [center]="center"
      [options]="mapOptions">
        <!-- clustered markers -->
        <map-marker-clusterer imagePath="assets/img/clusters/cluster_green">
          <map-marker
            *ngFor="let site of okSitesBound"
            [position]="site.position"
            [label]="site.type"
            [title]="site.displayName"
            [icon]="site.pinIcon"
            fit="true"
            [options]="okPinOptions">
          </map-marker>
        </map-marker-clusterer>
        <!-- unclustered markers -->
        <map-marker
          *ngFor="let site of notOkSitesBound"
          [position]="site.position"
          [label]="site.type"
          [title]="site.displayName"
          [icon]="site.pinIcon"
          fit="true"
          [options]="notOkPinOptions">
        </map-marker>
    </google-map>
  </div>
```

Here is my typescript:

```
  private subscribeToSiteDataReady(): void {
    this._siteDataReady.subscribe((ready: boolean) => {
      if (ready) {
        this.okSitesBound = this._okSitesUnbound;
        this.notOkSitesBound = this._notOkSitesUnbound;
        this.map.fitBounds({
          east: this._eastMostLng,
          west: this._westMostLng,
          north: this._northMostLat,
          south: this._southMostLat
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

^ The idea here is that when all the data for the pins are loaded in the unbound arrays (_okSitesUnbound and _notOkSitesUnbound), I emit the _siteDataReady event, and the subscription assigns the unbound arrays to the bound arrays (bound to the template). I do it this way because I want to separate the loading of the data from the rendering of the pins, so I bind the data to the template ONLY when it is fully loaded. This tells me the slow rendering of the pins is an issue with the map itself.

Here's some things I've tried:

- Clustering: as you can see from the code above, I have clustering enabled (https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps/map-marker-clusterer). But the clustering only comes into effect on small amounts of data (it renders a cluster icon immediately). But with large amounts of data, it seems to want to render all the pins first before clustering (and to be honest, I have yet to see the pins finish rendering with large amounts of data so I haven't actually seen clustering at all with large amounts of data; I'm assuming clustering happens after the pins are rendered).
- MarkerManager: This article (http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/) says that MarkerManager can be used to enhance the performance of pin rendering. But this seems to be available only for Google Maps (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markermanager), not Google Maps for Angular (@angular/google-maps 12.0.3). I tried instantiating a MarkerManager like this:

```
mgr = new google.maps.plugins.markermanager.MarkerManager(map, {});
```

...(taken from this example: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/packages/markermanager/examples/google_northamerica_offices.html), but it doesn't recognize the plugins namespace under google.maps.

Is there a way to speed up the rendering of the pins on Google Maps for Angular?

Comment: markermanager exists as an injectable for the angular maps library: https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/injectables/markermanager
Did you define the `GoogleMapsAPIWrapper` as a provider in your ngModule?

Comment: Here's an example I made with just one marker, but it shows a working markermanager:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-google-maps-demo-6ntwqc

Comment: Thanks nullptr, but unfortunately I'm not able to have @agm/core and @angular/google-maps installed at the same time. The GoogleMapsAPIWrapper seems to require @agm/core. I'm not finding an equivalent in @angular/google-maps.

Comment: @gib65 did you find a solution?

Comment: Does not matter if its angular or not… refer to KML layers to handle big load of data